# Show Bootstrap Modal via Typescript on Angular

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, bootstrap-4

So this is kinda a loose question, hoping someone can give me some ideas...
I have an Angular site where people fill in a form to register for an event.
People also have the ability to register themselves & other people at the same time.
[image]

What im trying to fix ~ when a person clicks "Add another ticket" it runs thru a method which first checks that all the fields are valid & they have ticked the checkbox (if they haven't then an alert box appears telling them which fields aren't valid)
That method then check's that there is sufficient tickets to register another person (this is what im currently working on - checking sufficient tickets).
If there are sufficient tickets (to register additional people) - then that person gets added to an array called 'attendees' & it clears the form - to add more people.

So when it checks for sufficient tickets (which is working) - if there aren't sufficient tickets to add more people, then the 'Add another ticket' button gets hidden, a modal window would appear (telling them no more tickets) so all then a user could do is click on 'pay now' (and pay for the people\tickets) they've lined up.

As 'Add another ticket' button can't really open\show the modal, then im trying to get the ts to show it.
right now (to test everything else) i just have the code launching an alert window - but an alert window is ugly.

Also note - "Add another ticket" (along with attendee fields) are a child component, while the rest of this screen is the parent component.
The parent has this method which is fired when the button on the child component is clicked.

```
public addAttendee(attendee: Attendee, waitlisted: boolean): void {
        //We only allow adding an attendee if all the fields are valid - so if fields aren't valid display error message & quit.
        console.log("Add attendee button clicked");
        this.attendeeComponent.AddAttendeeTermOfSale = true;
        if (!this.attendeeComponent.areTheseFieldsValid(true)) {
            this.areFormFieldsValid = false;
            this.errorMessages = this.invalidFieldsAttendee();
            //this.isAttendeeValid = false;
            return;
        } else {
            this.areFormFieldsValid = true;
            this.attendeeComponent.AddAttendeeTermOfSale = false; //we added an attendee with no validation error, so reset TermOFSale to false.
        }

        if (this.eventPassCapacityReached()){
            this.cantAddAdditionalAttendees(); 
            return;
            //check if enough passes.  if not, then display modal window.
        }
        //this.attendeeComponent.AddAttendeeTermOfSale
        if (this.isAttendeeCountExceedingEventCapacity()) {
            this.showEventCapacityExceedingErrorMessage();
            return;
        }...
    }
```

"EventPassCapacityReached" actually check's if there's enough tickets..

```
public eventPassCapacityReached() {
        let attendeesBeingRegistered = this.attendees.length;
        attendeesBeingRegistered += 1;
        this.sumPass = this.sumPass - attendeesBeingRegistered;

        if (this.sumPass <=0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

So im basically trying to change this alert window..

```
public cantAddAdditionalAttendees() {
        this.attendeeComponent.isPassesSoldOut = true;
        alert("dam... this was the last ticket for the event");
        var AddAttendeeButton = (<HTMLElement>document.getElementById("AddAnotherAttendee"));
        AddAttendeeButton.style.display = "none";
    }
```

here's my modal in the view

```
<div class="modal fade" tabindex="-1" id="noPassesModal" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="noPassesModalLabel" aria-hidden="true" data-target="noPassesModal">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <h4 class="modal-title">No additional tickets available</h4>
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                            </button>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                            <p>Unfortunately we don't have any additional tickets available for this event, and you wont be able to register additional people</p>
                            <p>If you have additional people who would like to come, we would suggest you contact our Events team via <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au">email</a> or by phone on 1800 161 236</p>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">
                            <div class="row">
                                        <!--<div class="col align-self-start">
                                            <a href="mailto:events@ceda.com.au?subject=Please transfer my session registration for {{ sessionData ? sessionData.sessionName : '' }}"
                                                role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Transfer</a>
                                        </div>-->
                                <div class="col align-self-end">
                                    <button role="button" class="btn btn-secondary btn-block">OK</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

So im trying to work out how to get the TS to show this modal (within "cantAddAdditionalAttendees")

Comment: [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/blob/master/libs/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/modal/src/components/modal-host/modal-host.component.ts#L44) how I render a modal using the angular CDK. The code can just be copy-pasted. [Here's](https://github.com/MintPlayer/mintplayer-ng-bootstrap/tree/master/apps/ng-bootstrap-demo/src/app/pages/overlay/modal) how to use it - [Demo](https://bootstrap.mintplayer.com/overlays/modals)

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to show the modal is by managing it with a boolean variable in the ts-file.

You can simply put it to 'true', when you want to show the modal (in your cantAddAdditionalAttendees method). In html you have to put it in *ngIf on your modal div.

That way you can show and hide your modal by manipulating the boolean variable.

When modals get bigger and contain more logic it makes sense to put them into a seperate component.

Another option would then be to use CDKComponentPortal to dynamically create the Modal components.

But the proposed way with the boolean variable should work in your use case.